# Autocentering picture in a control

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a kind of gallery wich can center to the most closer picture.
The controls that I think I can use are the HorizontalScrollView, but I need the trasition effect of centering in the middle of the closest picture. Any idea of examples or the control that I need to use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking for a [ViewFlow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow).  Or perhaps a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) + PagerAdapter.  For more on ViewPagers, have a look [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

They both have the same "snap to my closest view" effect, and page horizontally.  ViewPager is an official Android project and is probably the way to go, but if you don't want to deal with the Android Compatibility Library for earlier versions of Android (pre-Honeycomb) then ViewFlow may be easier.

Let me know if you need anything more!